# Is there a method to get ID of a way an edge belongs to?

Tags: java, openstreetmap, graphhopper

Is it possible? I need to jump to a way from any edge. Way ID seems very convenient mechanism considering it's already generated in OSM. However I can't find anything yet. If you wonder why I need this, it's simple - a way can be used as a container of common properties for a set of edges. It eliminates need to duplicate information.

```
    AllEdgesIterator ei = graph.getGraph().getAllEdges();

    logger.info("Wring {} edges...", ei.getMaxId());

    while (ei.next()) {
                // TODO (ds): get way ID here
                ...
    }
```

Comment: Hey, did you end up implementing a solution where you can backwards access OSM way and node meta data after they have been imported into Graphhopper?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember what I ended up with -- it's been a while

Answer (score 4):

The OSM way id is not stored in GraphHopper. You'll need to create e.g. an array of long values while import to maintain them:

```
arr[edgeId]=osmId
```

Comment: Yeah... I started adding that in OSMReader. It's a little bit involved because only OSMReader handles that when it creates edges. I am storing them with an edge and that requires a bit of work on serialization part.

Comment: Yeah, probably we should provide a hook for that. What do you mean with storing them with an edge? Do you mean you extend GraphHopperStorage to do that? You probably just need a DataAccess object (kind of an array but with serialization)

Comment: Not really. I added `wayId` to the edge and a couple accessors, `getWayId`, `setWayId`. Works fine. Unfortunately it caused significant hit on size :S Apparently adding 8 bytes, doubles size of the edge class and the edge file. From this perspective I wonder if I need `long` for way ID at all. GH defines it as `long` but I don't think OSM data goes beyond max int. The next thing is getting way tags available for analysis. GH is awesome, and I am sure I can make it be more informative.

Comment: BTW, I did try using approach similar to how way names are stored but then backed off because there isn't much but way ID to store. However for tags I will probably have to use `DataAccess` as you recommended because tags are numerous.

Comment: Yeah way ids are only 200K http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stats ... re tags: would also be nice to have in core GH e.g. via configuration. Maybe you can provide a PR :)